# pgadmin 4 Mac restore job is created but not working

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Whenever I try to restore a tar file to my database pgadmin 4 says restore job created but it never executes. I only see the restore job created dialog. After a refresh nothing changes. How can this be fixed? They do not support apparently pgadmin 3 anymore

**Using:**
Mac Sierra
Pgadmin 4

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in pgAdmin4 v1.1 and it is fixed in version 1.2

Please upgrade to latest version.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/2ebhu95.png) The sad part is I am running pgadmin 1.2 I downloaded the enterprisedb edition.

Comment: I was facing the same problem in Win10 when using ver 1.1 but after upgrading to v1.2 now it is working properly.

Comment: When I now try to restore I get the error exit code -6. http://i.imgur.com/X4Y33Pr.png

Comment: I have the same issue on Mojave with pgAdmin4 v4.16

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. For some reason, after I reinstalled pgadmin 4 EnterpriseDB and pgadmin 4 and copied the launcher from the non-enterprise version into the program folder it worked.

I already had a Postgress folder where the pgadmin launcher resided and some other stuff installed by pgadmin.